# CiviCRM update repeat activity Issue

Tags: activities

i am using CiviCRM 5.66.0.

From users i can create activity and also create repeat activities for multiple occurrence. Let's say i have create repeat activity for Jan 4, 2024, Feb 4, 2024, March 4, 2024 and Aprill 4, 2024. After creating if i now try to edit March 4 and click save their is a option only this activity
[image]

After select only this activity and save the repeated activities were supposed to be reincurring each month from Jan to April, but the activities become from Mar to Jun.
How to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: It may be worth your trying to replicate this on one of the sites such as https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ to confirm the behaviour on a vanilla system

Comment: Hello, i am using CiviCRM with WordPress. So, the mentioned link is for drupal. now, what should my next step?

Comment: Google for 'civicrm demo wordpress' works https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/